# how to implement OnItemClickListener at class level

Tags: android

I have two `listview` inside class and I don't want to implement `OnClickListener` for each `listview` rather I want the class to implement `OnClickListener` and handle both listview OnClicklistener in single overriden method `OnClickListener`.
Can anyone help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class ListViewContainer implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
ListView listView1;
ListView listView2;
private void someMethod(){
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(parent == listView1){
        //Do Listview 1 things
    }else if(parent == listView2){
        //Do Listview 2 things
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener getItemClickListener(){

    return new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
};
...
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
listView2.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```