# AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

Tags: java, android, interface, listener

i want to ask how we do

`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener Listener new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`

altough **AdapterView.OnItemClickListener** is an interface

and  i know that **An interface can't be instantiated**

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829806/how-to-implement-onitemclicklistener-at-class-level?

Comment: You're not instantiating the interface, there. You're instantiating the anonymous class that's defined by the interface name, and the class body in the following `{...}` block.